# Plotly scatter large volume geographic data

Tags: python, plotly, visualization, scatter, large-data-volumes

I tried to write a code that creates a visualization of all forest fires that happened during the year 2021. The CSV file containing the data is around 1.5Gb, the program looks correct for me, but when I try to run it, it gets stuck without displaying any visualization or error message. The last time I tried, it run for almost half a day until python crashed.
I don't know if I am having an infinite loop, if that's because the file is too big or if there is something else I am missing.
Can anyone provide feedback, please?

Here is my code:

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime
from plotly.graph_objs import Scattergeo , Layout
from plotly import offline

filename='fire_nrt_J1V-C2_252284.csv'
with open(filename) as f:
    reader=csv.reader(f)
    header_row=next(reader)
    

    lats, lons, brights, dates=[],[],[],[]
    for row in reader:
        date=datetime.strptime(row[5], '%Y-%m-%d')
        lat=row[0]
        lon=row[1]
        bright=row[2]
        lats.append(lat)
        lons.append(lon)
        brights.append(bright)
        dates.append(date)

data=[{
    'type':'scattergeo',
    'lon':lons,
    'lat':lats,
    'text':dates,
    'marker':{
        'size':[5*bright for bright in brights],
        'color': brights,
        'colorscale':'Reds',
        'colorbar': {'title':'Fire brightness'},

    }
}]

my_layout=Layout(title="Forestfires during the year 2021")
fig={'data':data,'layout':my_layout}
offline.plot(fig, filename='global_fires_2021.html')
```

Comment: A simple way to check which of the two is the case: cut up your csv file to something with only a few lines, and see what happens. This is usually one of the first steps in the [mcve] process, so it's worth reading that article and then trying to reduce your own code/data accordingly.

Comment: Is `1.5Go` meant to be `1.5 Gb` or `1.5 Gib` or something else? Also, have you run the program in a debugger? What happened then?

Comment: Have you tried removing entries from the CSV file to see if this makes a difference? I would start out with a small CSV file to verify that everything is working as it should with a small subset of data.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman yeah 1.5GB sorry for that!


I didn't try to run it with a smaller CSV file as I couldn't open the file with my text editor (because it is too big)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- have found data you describe here https://wifire-data.sdsc.edu/dataset/viirs-i-band-375-m-active-fire-data/resource/3ce73b20-f584-44f7-996b-2f319c480294
- **plotly** uses resources for every point plotted on a scatter.  So there is a limit before you run out of resources
- there are other approaches to plotting larger number of points

  - https://plotly.com/python/mapbox-density-heatmaps/ fewer limits, but still limited on very large data sets
  - https://plotly.com/python/datashader/ can work with very large data sets as it generates an image.  It is more challenging to work with (install and navigate API)

#### data sourcing

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = pd.read_csv("https://firms.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/data/active_fire/noaa-20-viirs-c2/csv/J1_VIIRS_C2_Global_7d.csv")
df
```

#### scatter_geo

- limited to random sample of 1000 rows

```
px.scatter_geo(
    df.sample(1000),
    lat="latitude",
    lon="longitude",
    color="bright_ti4",
    # size="size",
    hover_data=["acq_date"],
    color_continuous_scale="reds",
)
```

[image]

#### density mapbox

```
px.density_mapbox(
    df.sample(5000),
    lat="latitude",
    lon="longitude",
    z="bright_ti4",
    radius=3,
    color_continuous_scale="reds",
    zoom=1,
    mapbox_style="carto-positron",
)
```

[image]

#### datashader Mapbox

- all data
- some libraries are more difficult to install and use
- need to deal with this issue https://community.plotly.com/t/datashader-image-distorted-when-passed-to-mapbox/39375/2

```
import datashader as ds, colorcet
from pyproj import Transformer

t3857_to_4326 = Transformer.from_crs(3857, 4326, always_xy=True)

# project CRS to ensure image overlays appropriately back over mapbox
# https://community.plotly.com/t/datashader-image-distorted-when-passed-to-mapbox/39375/2
df.loc[:, "longitude_3857"], df.loc[:, "latitude_3857"] = ds.utils.lnglat_to_meters(
    df.longitude, df.latitude
)

RESOLUTION=1000
cvs = ds.Canvas(plot_width=RESOLUTION, plot_height=RESOLUTION)
agg = cvs.points(df, x="longitude_3857", y="latitude_3857")
img = ds.tf.shade(agg, cmap=colorcet.fire).to_pil()

fig = go.Figure(go.Scattermapbox())
fig.update_layout(
    mapbox={
        "style": "carto-positron",
        "layers": [
            {
                "sourcetype": "image",
                "source": img,
                # Sets the coordinates array contains [longitude, latitude] pairs for the image corners listed in
                # clockwise order: top left, top right, bottom right, bottom left.
                "coordinates": [
                    t3857_to_4326.transform(
                        agg.coords["longitude_3857"].values[a],
                        agg.coords["latitude_3857"].values[b],
                    )
                    for a, b in [(0, -1), (-1, -1), (-1, 0), (0, 0)]
                ],
            }
        ],
    },
    margin={"l": 0, "r": 0, "t": 0, "r": 0},
)
```

[image]